# Create hrefs with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app. + Thymeleaf, I have this piece of code:

and I want to create a link like this: `/swans/3/tommy.html`

so I create this piece of code:

```
<a th:href="@{/swans/{id}/{name}.html(id=${user.id},name=$(user.name))}" target="_blank">
```

but I have this error when init the app:.

Could not parse as expression: "@{/swans/{id}/{name}.html(id=${user.id},name=$(user.name))}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the typo. For variables, you need to use curly brackets ...

```
<a th:href="@{/swans/{id}/{name}.html(id=${user.id},name=${user.name})}" target="_blank">
```

More information on [Link URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).